# Is it possible to bind a control to two data source controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a DetailsView Control. In `EditItemTemplate`, I replaced the `TextBox** with **DropDownList**.

For `DropDownList`, there is `XmlDataSource`.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="130px"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("team") %>' DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="companyname" DataValueField="companyname">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="~/App_Data/xml/teams.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

</EditItemTemplate>
```

Problem is here:
For **DetailsView** Control, I have **DataSource** as **SqlDataSource**

Does it mean I am trying to bind one single control to two different datasources ? How to bind DropDownList1 so that I am able to save the SelectedValue and do not get the following error?

I get the following error when I try to edit

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList1'
>   has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the
>   list of items. Parameter name: value
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue
>   which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
>   Parameter name: value]

Answer (score 0):

There's a contradiction between what you're binding and what the value is. You're binding team but the value is companyname and they should match.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="130px"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("team") %>' DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="companyname" DataValueField="companyname">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks @wazz but it did not work You rightly pointed out the contradiction but **'team'** is fieldname in table from **Sqldatasource** which is (bound to GridView) required for updating table, **'companyname'** was from **XmlDataSource** bound to dropdownlist1. I changed the companyname to team.

Comment: Sry, what i meant was, I *think* you can do this, but the names will have to be the same in the data source as well as the code. i don't think the data source has to be the exact same (?) but it has to appear to be the same. For ex, if you had a previous version of a database that you had to go back to, you could, because it's the same structurally, but not physically the same. Can you change the xml file before using it?

Answer (score 0):

This may help other users -

Instead of binding the DropDownList of EditItemTemplate (DetailsView) to any specific DataSource, I achieved this by using ItemUpding event. So I completely avoided *SelectedValue='<%# Bind("team") %>'*

HTML Code now looks like this -

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="130px"
                        DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" DataTextField="team" DataValueField="team" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind now looks like this -

```
 protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)


         {
                DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1");

                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["team"].DefaultValue = dropDownList.SelectedValue;
    }
```